# Xamarin - HtmlWebViewSource and XAML

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I trying to display an HTML from a model inside of `WebView` control. After some googling, I realised that I cannot use the Source property as it is meant to be populated only with URL or URI.

After a couple additional searches, I came across `HtmlWebViewSource` but I can't find a single example of using `HtmlWebViewSource` via XAML.

Does anyone have a clue how to define an instance of  `HtmlWebViewSource` in XAML, bind HTML from the model and assign it to `WebView`

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To answer myself

```
<WebView x:Name="_webView" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
     <WebView.Source>
         <HtmlWebViewSource
         Html="{Binding HTMLSource}" />
     </WebView.Source>
</WebView>
```